# Breaking the golden rules on FOR loops with R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

Firstly, apologies as this may seem a bit long winded, but I hope to give as much information on this problem as I can...

I have written a script that loops through a set of files defined in a csv file. Each file within this csv listing is an XML file, each one is for a particular event in an application, and all files within this list are of the same event type. However, each file can contain different data. For instance, one could hold an attribute with no child nodes beneath, while others contain nodes.

My script works perfectly fine, but when it gets to about XML file 5000, it has slowed down considerably. 
Problem is that my code creates a blank dataframe initially, and then grows is at new columns are detected.

I understand that this is a big NO NO when it comes to writing R FOR loops, but am unsure how to get around this problem, give my smallest file listing is 69000, which makes going through each one in turn and counting the nodes a task in itself.

Are there any ideas on how to get around this?

pseudo code or actual R code to do this would be great. So would ideas/opinions, as I am unsure on the best approach to this task.

Here is my current code.

```
library(XML)
library(xml2)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(foreign)
library(rio)


# Get file data to be used
#
setwd('c:/temp/xml')
headerNames <- c('GUID','EventId','AppId','RequestFile', 'AE_Type', 'AE_Drive')
GetNames    <- rowid_to_column(read.csv(file= 'c:/temp/xml/R_EventIdA.csv', fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", header = FALSE, col.names = headerNames),'ID')

inputfiles <- as.character(GetNames[,5]) # Gets list of files


# Create empty dataframes
#
df             <- data.frame()
transposed.df1 <- data.frame()
allxmldata     <- data.frame()

findchildren<-function(nodes, df) {

  numchild <- sapply(nodes, function(x){length(xml_children(x))})
  xml.value <- xml_text(nodes[numchild==0])
  xml.name  <- xml_name(nodes[numchild==0])
  xml.path  <- sapply(nodes[numchild==0], function(x) {gsub(', ','_', toString(rev(xml_name(xml_parents(x)))))})
  fieldname <- paste(xml.path,xml.name,sep = '_')
  contents <- sapply(xml.value, function(f){is.na(f)<-which(f == '');f})

  if (length(fieldname) > 0) {
    fieldname <- paste(fieldname,xml.value, sep = '_')
    dftemp <- data.frame(fieldname, contents)
    df       <- rbind(df, dftemp)
    print(dim(df))
  }
  if (sum(numchild)>0){
    findchildren(xml_children(nodes[numchild>0]), df) }
  else{ return(df)
  }
}

findchildren2<-function(nodes, df){
  numchild<-sapply(nodes, function(embeddedinputfile){length(xml_children(embeddedinputfile))})
  xmlvalue<-xml_text(nodes[numchild==0])
  xmlname<-xml_name(nodes[numchild==0])
  xmlpath<-sapply(nodes[numchild==0], function(embeddedinputfile) {gsub(', ','_', toString(rev(xml_name(xml_parents(embeddedinputfile)))))})
  fieldname<-paste(xmlpath,xmlname,sep = '_')
  contents<-sapply(xmlvalue, function(f){is.na(f)<-which(f == '');f})
  if (length(fieldname) > 0) {
    dftemp<-data.frame(fieldname, contents)
    df<-rbind(df, dftemp)
    print(dim(df))
  }
  if (sum(numchild)>0){
    findchildren2(xml_children(nodes[numchild>0]), df) }
  else{ return(df)
  }
}


# Loop all files
#
for (x in inputfiles) {

  df1     <- findchildren(xml_children(read_xml(x)),df)

  ## original xml dataframe

  if (length(df1) > 0) {
    xml.df1 <- data.frame(spread(df1, key = fieldname, value = contents), fix.empty.names = TRUE)
  }

  ##
  xml.df1 %>%
    pluck('Response_RawData') -> rawxml
  if (length(rawxml)>0) {
    df.rawxml <- data.frame(rawxml)
    export(df.rawxml,'embedded.xml')
    embeddedinputfile <-as.character('embedded.xml')
    rm(df1)
    df1 <- findchildren2(xml_children(read_xml(embeddedinputfile)),df)

    if (length(df1) > 0) {
      xml.df2 <- spread(df1, key = fieldname, value = contents)
    }
    allxmldata <- rbind.fill(allxmldata,cbind(xml.df1,xml.df2))
  } else {
    allxmldata <- rbind.fill(allxmldata,cbind(xml.df1))
  }
}

if(nrow(allxmldata)==nrow(GetNames)) {
  alleventdata<-cbind(GetNames,allxmldata)
}

dbConn2 <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=PC-XYZ;database=Events;trusted_connection=true')


sqlSave(dbConn2, alleventdata, tablename = 'AE_EventA', append = TRUE )
```

Comment: This sounds like memory a memory limitation rather than your perhaps unorthodox use of for loops.  In any case, please include your code so that we may help you.

Comment: It looks like in case `length(df1) <= 0` you would process the same `xml.df1` a second time?

Comment: No. The idea is that 'if length(df1) > 0' this is to switch rows to columns, and will only need to do it if there is something in there.